# Can I interrupt function if it is executed for too long?

Tags: c++, signals

I a have third party function which I use in my program. I can't replace it; it's in a dynamic library, so I also can't edit it. The problem is that it sometimes runs for too long.

So, can I do anything to stop this function from running if it runs more than 10 seconds for example? (It's OK to close program in this scenario.)

PS. I have Linux, and this program won't have to be ported anywhere else.

What I want is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func1 (void) // I can not change contents of this.
{
  int i; // random
  while (i % 2 == 0);
}

int main ()
{
  setTryTime(10000);
  timeTry{
     func1();
  } catchTime {
     puts("function executed too long, aborting..");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but are you sure you want to?  Be careful about it, especially if you have threads around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  And you'd do it just the way you suggested in your title: "signals".

Specifically, an "alarm" signal:

- http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm
- http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/signals.html

Comment: Note that you can't safely break out of a function using a signal, as there's no telling what state it's in. There's also some limitations on what you can do safely in a signal handler; about all you can do here is carefully print a message to stderr and call `exit()`.

Comment: You cannot print a message to `stderr` because that involves a locking on the `FILE *` object. And locking is not safe to do in a signal handler. You can easily end up with a deadlock. Unless.. you call `write` on `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: Thanks, all answers were informative, but this is exactly what I needed. you saved the day.

Comment: Cool. And for whatever it's worth, "classic" signals are entirely safe and very useful the vast majority of the time.  You shouldn't have any problems.  Even if you "fprintf (stderr, ...)" in your signal handler ;)  IMHO...

Answer (score 3):

If you really have to do this, you probably want to spawn a process that does nothing but invoke the function and return its result to the caller. If it runs too long, you can kill that process.

By putting it into its own process, you stand a decent (not great, but decent) chance of cleaning up at least most of what it was doing so when it dies unexpectedly it *probably* won't make a complete mess of things that will lead to later problem.

Answer (score 0):

The potential problem with forcefully cancelling a running function is that it may "own" resources that it intended to return later.  The kind of resources that can be problems include:

- heap memory allocations (free store)
- shared memory segments
- threads
- sockets
- file handles
- locks

Some of these resources are managed on a per-process basis, so letting the function run in a different process (perhaps using `fork`) makes it easier to kill cleanly.  Other resources can outlive a process, and really must be cleaned up explicitly.  Depending on your operating system, it's also possible that the function may be part-way through interacting with some hardware driver or device, and killing it unexpectedly may leave that driver or device in a bizarre state such that it won't work until after a restart.

If you happen to know that the function doesn't use any of these kind of resources, then you can kill it confidently. But, it's hard to guarantee that: in a large system with many such decisions - which the compiler can't check - evolution of code in functions like `func1()` is likely to introduce dependencies on such resources.

If you must do this, I'd suggest running it in a different process or thread, and using `kill()` for processes, `pthread_kill` if func1() has some support for terminating when a flag is set asynchronously, or the non-portable `pthread_cancel` if there's really no other choice.